# Send 2nd value to AJAX, Rails 4

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have built simple payment system. A part from system is autorize user to create advertisement, but before it can happen user has to fill in text field simple confirmation code. Code is from SMS.

I added AJAX blur so when focus is lost application would check if confirmation code is valid.

So far I have like this:

In **SMS controller**:

```
@token = ('0'..'9').to_a.shuffle.first(5).join
@payment.token_salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
@payment.token_hash = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(@token,  @payment.token_salt)
```

I am not saving token as plain text, I am saving just salt and hash as security precaution. It works great.

In **Advertisement controller:**

```
def checktoken

      @payment =   Payment.where('identifier = ?', params[:identifier])
         if @payment.present?
              if @payment.token_hash == BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(params[:token], @payment.token_salt)
                render :nothing => true, :status => 200
              else
                   render :nothing => true, :status => 409
              end
         else
               render :nothing => true, :status => 409
          end
       return
    end
```

This method would find required advertisement by `identifier` and then check if given token hash is the same as in database. So I need 2 values to get to work this code. `params[:token]` and `params [:identifier]`

I managed to send first one:

In form:

```
  <% text_field(:identifier,:value=> @advertisement.identifier, :'data-validate' => '/advertisements/checktoken')  %>

     <%= text_field(:token,:placeholder=> "Kods *" ,:'data-validate' => '/advertisements/checktoken')  %>
```

In **routes.rb**

```
collection do
     get 'checktoken'
  end
```

My script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-validate]').blur(function() {
        $this = $(this);
        $.get($this.data('validate'), {
            token: $this.val()
        }).success(function() {
            $this.removeClass('field_with_errors');
        }).error(function() {
            $this.addClass('field_with_errors');
        });
    });
});
```

**Question is how to pass @advertisement.identifier variable value in the same maner as I am doing with token ?**

I googled for this, but there wasn't valid examples just how to do with single value.

Any help would be great.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set `id` attribute on those fields and you can use it later as selector.

In your view:

```
<%= text_field(
      :identifier,
      :value => @advertisement.identifier,
      :'data-validate' => '/advertisements/checktoken',
      :id => 'identifier_field'
) %>
<%= text_field(
      :token,
      :placeholder => "Kods *",
      :'data-validate' => '/advertisements/checktoken'
      :id => 'token_field'
) %>
```

In your javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('[data-validate]').blur(function() {
    $this = $(this);
    $.get($this.data('validate'), {
      token: $('#token_field').val(),
      identifier: $('#identifier_field').val()
    }).success(function() {
      $this.removeClass('field_with_errors');
    }).error(function() {
      $this.addClass('field_with_errors');
    });
  });
});
```